# Best way to allow access to MySQL database for roaming users

Tags: mysql, security

Currently I have a Windows Application that I made that several companies use. Each one has their own privileges based upon a name and their public IP address to their own database.
I have a few users that travel and will not know their IP addresses in advance.

Can anyone offer some advice as to the best way to allow them access to their database, without me having to open up their database access to all IP addresses? Or is there really no way around this?

Keep in mind I am a newb when it comes to mysql stuff. But I am willing to learn!

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What type of things are they doing? Are they making changes, just viewing content, etc.? How are they connecting currently? (i.e. what client)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way is to use a road-warrior VPN configuration and have static IP addresses assigned to each 'warrior' which you can use in Mysql as the host field. Check out OpenVPN for example.

Example: http://zeldor.biz/2011/05/openvpn-road-warrior-setup/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening it to all IP addresses and using very strong names and passwords.